# Get User posted Content from wordpress to Other website using Ajax request

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I have one wordpress and other HTML website. In my wordpress contain user posts. I need to get the content from wordpress site to my HTML website using AJAX request.

I will pass user email Id through the AJAX request ,from this request i need to get the specified user posted content from wordpress. Is it possible.Please suggest the better option.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can get user details from

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_user_id

[to get this you would need to install some plugin, that help you to run PHP in wordpress Environment]

Then you can use ajax to place appropriate data, to other web services or web page.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: I need to get the user posted content from wordpress to my HTML website .I  can only pass the email Id to the wordpress .Because the user id in my HTML website and wordpress are different. I this scenario how can i get the user posted content to My HTML website. Your this answer is not useful for me.